# javascript private member not accessible through public method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have following setup. method and method1 both are public methods of class Student. But why ca only "method" access private variable p

```
​function Student() {
    var p = 10;
    this.method = function() {
        document.write(p);
    }; 
};

Student.prototype.method1 = function() {
    document.write('here');
    document.write(p);
};

var s = new Student();
s.method();
s.method1();
​
```

How does it make sense, I mean is it "a public method that does not have access to private members!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magic going on with JavaScript's prototypal inheritance.

`Student` is still a function and `p` is local to that function. It cannot be accessed from outside code in any way. `method` can access `p` because it is defined inside `Student` and therefore forms a closure, but `method1` is declared outside `Student`'s scope.

Assigning a function to another function's prototype cannot give it access to its local variables.

Consider this example:

```
var p = 41;

function foo() {
    console.log(p);
}

​function Student(){
    var p = 10;
};

Student.prototype.bar = foo;

var s = new Student();
s.bar();
foo();
```

You might think that because `foo` is invoked as an object method it could have access to the local variables, but that's just not the case. The only value that is determined dynamically is `this`, it is a special keyword. All other variables are strictly defined through the scope chain.

Answer (score 0):

method1 is defined outside of the base class definition for Student.  As such, it cannot access variables declared as private inside the base class definition.  If it could, then you could get around private variable restrictions in existing classes by just defining a public method for that class.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, public methods like `method1` (i.e. methods added to the prototype) do not have access to private variables, but "privileged" methods like your `method` do.

Remember, JavaScript doesn't have the same scoping rules as other object-oriented languages. The `method` method forms a closure around the private variables within the `Student` constructor function, while `method1` does not.

Comment: Hit mine too.  World's most anonymous troll?

Comment: @BenBarden, don't worry I've upvoted your answer as there is nothing wrong with it!